# Using 'dpkg' in Python causes OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, subprocess, vscode-extensions, dpkg

I built a script to find the most recent version of Visual Studio Code, download it and install it on an Ubuntu machine with dpkg.  I haven't found a decent Python library for doing this and am using subprocess.call() to invoke a Shell command.  This certainly may not be the best way to do it, but this is also a learning project.

It successfully downloads the file and places it in my ~/Downloads dir.  When I try to invoke the subprocess.call(), it spits back 'OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor'

I know my command string is correct.  I can invoke it just fine from the CLI.  But it doesn't work when called through subprocess.

Any advice on doing this more efficiently is welcome.

```
"""
Python 3 script
Downloads the latest .deb package for installing VSCode, and installs it 
"""
import os               # used to direct where to save downloaded file
import subprocess       # used to derive filepath of CLI arg
import requests         # py3 only
import platform         # used to detect the OS
from urllib.request import urlopen, ContentTooShortError, urlretrieve # py3 version of 'import urllib2'

HOME = os.path.expanduser('~')
filePath = HOME + "/Downloads"
fileName = 'vs_code_most_recent_amd64.deb'
outputName = os.path.join(filePath, fileName)
alreadyDownloaded = False

# used in subprocess calls to suppress stdout or stderr
pipeToDevNull = open(os.devnull, 'w')

def IsDownloadable(url):
    """
    Check of the link passed in is a downloadable file. Used to shortcut the 
    processing so that it doesn't attempt to download a URL that isn't 
    downloadable.  Returns True or False.
    """
    h = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True)
    header = h.headers
    contentType = header.get('content-type')
    if 'text' in contentType.lower():
        return False
    if 'html' in contentType.lower():
        return False
    return True

def DownloadVSCodePkg(url):
    """
    Downloads the file at the specified URL, save it as the above-defined filename
    """
    u = urlopen(url)

    f = open(outputName, 'wb')
    meta = u.info()

    fileSize = int(meta.get_all("Content-Length")[0])    

    fileSizeDL = 0
    #blockSize = 8192
    blockSize = 16384

    while True:
        buffer = u.read(blockSize)
        if not buffer:
            break
        fileSizeDL += len(buffer)
        f.write(buffer)
        status = r"%10d Bytes [%3.2f%%]" % (fileSizeDL, fileSizeDL * 100. / fileSize)
        status = status + chr(8)*(len(status)+1)
        print("Downloading: {0}".format(status), end="\r", flush=True)
    print("Downloading: {0}".format(status))
    print("Downloaded: {0}".format(fileName))
    f.close()
    del f


def CheckDownloadSuccess():
    """
    returns bool value if the file we want is in the dir specified
    """
    try:
        subprocess.check_call("ls " + outputName, stdout=pipeToDevNull, stderr=pipeToDevNull, shell=True)
        return True
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        return False

def UnpackAndInstall():
    """
    Invokes dpkg from the linux shell and installs VSCode.
    """
    #Detect OS
    linuxDistro = platform.linux_distribution()
    OSType = linuxDistro[0]

    if OSType == 'Ubuntu':
        from apt.debfile import DebPackage
        pkg = DebPackage(outputName)
        command = 'sudo dpkg -i ' + outputName

        #The thing that attempts to unpack:
        try:
            subprocess.check_call(command, stdout=subprocess.STDOUT, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            print("Install Failed.")

def main():
    url = 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=760868'

    alreadyDownloaded = CheckDownloadSuccess()

    if alreadyDownloaded is False:
        if IsDownloadable(url):
            DownloadVSCodePkg(url)            
            # check if the download succeeded, if file doesn't already exist.
            if CheckDownloadSuccess():
                print("Download Successful!\nFile location => " + outputName)
            else:
                print("Download Failed...")

        else:
            print('Link broken: need to update the package resource link.')
    else:
        print("File already exists.")

    UnpackAndInstall()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the traceback and the error from the CLI:

```
$ python3 setupVSCode.py 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setupVSCode.py", line 192, in <module>
    main()
  File "setupVSCode.py", line 189, in main
    UnpackAndInstall()
  File "setupVSCode.py", line 95, in UnpackAndInstall
    subprocess.call(command, stdout=subprocess.STDOUT, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 267, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: You're mixing forward/backwards slashes.

Comment: Well, your Python code that does the actual execution looks ok.  I assume the error comes from proper (from Python's view) execution of the 'dpkg' command (quite possibly due to problems with your file path, as @David says).  I would suggest doing two things:

1) print the value of 'command' so you see exactly what you're trying to run, and 2) try running that same command without Python involved.  NOTE: I didn't spend the time to study your code.  These suggestions are just what I do whenever I have a case like this involving subprocess.xxx

Answer (score 2):

`os.path.expanduser('~')` is going to return something like: `'C:\\Users\\user.name'` which you're appending `'/Downloads'`, resulting in a bad path like: `'C:\\Users\\user.name/Downloads\\'`

Instead of:

```
filePath = HOME + "/Downloads"
```

Do:

```
filePath = HOME + "\Downloads"
```

Or preferably:

```
filePath = os.path.join(HOME, 'Downloads')
```

Comment: An alternative (which I like to recommend whenever anyone is using `os`) is to use `pathlib.Path`: `HOME = pathlib.Path.home()`; `file_path = HOME / "Downloads"`.

Comment: Nice answer(s) - I'll just plug the idea I propose in the comments so that the OP can benefit.  If you printed what you're executing, you'd see this problem immediately.  It's a very powerful tool to have in your toolbox.

Comment: Does it make a difference that this is on a Linux box for the forward vs backslashes?  I'm not writing this for Windows.

Comment: In my specific machine's case, os.path.expanduser gives "/home/bcuser" on my ubuntu system.

Comment: Absolutely it matters which you use!  If you aren't programming for windows, stay far away from backwards slashes in paths. - the best answer, which is more tedious but more correct (I should do it more, but I don't) is to use path.join() and other support functions so that there are no forward or backward slashes in your code (which I see you're already doing some).  Such code would run on Windows too.  (but of course, who cares about Windoze, LOL)

Comment: Did you try printing the 'command' variable just before you run it?  This really is a lifesaver.  Then you can SEE just what you're trying to run, and know immediately (hopefully) why it's still wrong.  I'd really like to see that command.  Maybe you could print it and post it here.

Comment: Yes I did.  I've tried copy-pasting the 'command' variable into the CLI directly and it works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188847/discussion-between-steve-and-bretonator).

Answer (score 1):

After speaking with @Steve, I tried removing the output redirectors on the subprocess.call().

The advice on removing all slashes in path construction and instead using "os.path.join()" has been implemented and will be followed as a best practice from here on.

Since the command as constructed worked fine from the CLI, it was a matter of thinking about what the subprocess.call() did that was different.  It redirected output.  With that removed things work fine

It now looks like so:

```
 HOME = os.path.expanduser('~')
 filePath = os.path.join(HOME, "Downloads")
 fileName = 'vs_code_most_recent_amd64.deb'
 outputName = os.path.join(filePath, fileName)
 alreadyDownloaded = False
 ...
 command = 'sudo dpkg -i ' + outputName

 try:
     subprocess.check_call(command, shell=True)
 except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
     print("Install Failed.")
```